# Report Generator Nuget in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, code-coverage, reportgenerator

I am not able to install Report Generator plugin in VS 2015 professional. I want to use report generator and open cover to get code coverage reports.How can i install report generator ?[image]

Comment: Restart Visual Studio. If that won't help, select Default project from drop down list. If that won't help, use `-ProjectName` flag like `Install-Package ReportGenerator -ProjectName MyProject -Version 4.0.0-alpha12`

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi Leo , I m now using VS2015 enterprise inbuilt code coverage tool. So i haven't tried installing the plugin again.

Answer (score 1):

> Report Generator Nuget in Visual Studio

Please select a project name in the drop-down menu of the Default project on the Package Manager Console:

[image]

If the drop down menu is **empty**, please check if there is a project open in your solution (Project should not be unloaded), otherwise, your project type may not support nuget, like `SQL Server DateBase project`. You can right click your project in the Solution Explorer, the Manage NuGet Packages option should be grayed out in the right-click extension list:

[image]